# I Want to get the value of the selected element but it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="select-box">
                        <div class="options-container">
                            @foreach($categories as $cat)
                            <div class="option">
                                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="{{$cat->name}}" value="{{$cat>name}}" name="subcategory" />
                                <label  for="{{$cat->name}}">{{$cat->name}}</label>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>

                        <div class="selected">
                            Sélectionner une categories
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
$(".radio").on('change', function () {
    var radioValue = $(".selected").innerHTML;

    alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question well and you want to take the content/text inside the class `.selected` , you can use this

`var radioValue = $(".selected").html()`

OR

`var radioValue = $(".selected").text()`

instead of

`var radioValue = $(".selected").innerHTML`

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
$(".radio").on('change', function () {
   var radioValue = $(this).val();
   alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
});
```

$(this) will select attributes from the specific radio button that was clicked.

Working code : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/xbhef28L/2/)